# How to return values with the return statement in python?

Tags: python, return

I'm writing a program that returns the train prices. When I run the function nothing is returning.

```
def transit(zone, ticket):
    fareLst = ['23', '11.5', '34.5']

    if zone < 2 and ticket == 'adult':
        return fareLst[0]

    elif zone < 2 and ticket == 'child':
        return fareLst[1]

    elif zone > 4 and ticket == 'adult':
         return -1


def main():
    transit(1, 'adult')   # the function is not returning the fareLst = 23


main()
```

Comment: Why are your `fareLst` values stored as strings? Shouldn't they be either `float` or `Decimal`?

Comment: @user3339203: you are supposed to accept one of the answers (unless none of them are good); you have asked many questions on SO and most of them don't have an accepted answer. Other people are putting their time into helping you; the least you can do is show your appreciation by giving them credit.

Answer (score 5):

The function *is* returning the value; you're just not doing anything with it. You can print it if you want:

```
def main():
    print transit(1, 'adult')
```

`return` is not the same as printing something on the screen; return values are used like this, for example:

```
smth = transit(1, 'adult')
```

You don't want everything that you ever return to be printed out automatically.

---

Also, on another note, you should use proper floating point values to store floating point data, instead of strings:

```
fareLst = [23.0, 11.5, 34.5]
```

Also, note that if you call `transit(5, 'child')`, it will return nothing/`None`... so you might want this at the end of your `if-elif` block:

```
else:
    return -1
```

instead of:

```
elif zone > 4 and ticket == 'adult':
     return -1
```

...although `None` might also be a viable option for e.g. completely invalid input; but then again, an exception would be even better in that case.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to just print out the result, do the following:

```
def main():
    print transit(1,'adult')
```

or if you want to store the variable and print it later, do the following:

```
def main():
    result = transit(1,'adult')
    #do something
    print result
```

Comment: whoever downvoted this answer — why? there's nothing wrong or missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already mentioned that you're not storing the return value, but I'll also add that you have no default "base case" at the end. In this code:

```
def transit(zone, ticket):
    fareLst = ['23', '11.5', '34.5']

    if zone < 2 and ticket == 'adult':
        return fareLst[0]

    elif zone < 2 and ticket == 'child':
        return fareLst[1]

    elif zone > 4 and ticket == 'adult':
         return -1
```

what if `zone` is equal to 2, 3, or 4? What if `zone` is 4 but `ticket` is child? All of those would fall through to the end, and the default return value of a function is `None`. That's probably not what you want. If not, add something like `return 20` or whatever a sensible default ticket price would be.

Also, it's not Pythonic to return sentinel values like in the final case above. A more Pythonic approach would be to raise a `ValueError` if the parameters are bad, then wrap your calling code in a `try/except` block. That leaves no room for ambiguity, and checking return values is a pain in the neck.

Comment: For the record: I actually did mention the missing default case in my answer ~13 min ago :P